# WSO2 websocket + SockJS - Cross origin requests blocked

Tags: websocket, wso2, sockjs, wso2-esb

Since WSO2 5.0 supports WebSockets, I have written a simple app following by tutorials:

- [WebSocket Transport](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/WebSocket+Transport)
- [Sending a Message from a WebSocket Client to an HTTP Endpoint](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sending+a+Message+from+a+WebSocket+Client+to+an+HTTP+Endpoint)

Here's my source view output from WSO2:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.WSO2Registry">
        <parameter name="cachableDuration">15000</parameter>
    </registry>
    <taskManager provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskTaskManager"/>
    <sequence name="fault">
        <!-- Log the message at the full log level with the ERROR_MESSAGE and the ERROR_CODE-->
        <log level="full">
            <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default 'fault' sequence"/>
            <property expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')" name="ERROR_CODE"/>
            <property expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" name="ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
        </log>
        <!-- Drops the messages by default if there is a fault -->
        <drop/>
    </sequence>
    <sequence name="main">
        <in>
            <!-- Log all messages passing through -->
            <log level="full"/>
            <!-- ensure that the default configuration only sends if it is one of samples -->
            <!-- Otherwise Synapse would be an open proxy by default (BAD!)               -->
            <filter regex="http://localhost:9000.*" source="get-property('To')">
                <!-- Send the messages where they have been sent (i.e. implicit "To" EPR) -->
                <send/>
            </filter>
        </in>
        <out>
            <send/>
        </out>
        <description>The main sequence for the message mediation</description>
    </sequence>
    <sequence name="outDispatchSeq">
        <log level="full"/>
        <respond/>
    </sequence>
    <sequence name="dispatchSeq">
        <switch
            source="get-property('websocket.source.handshake.present')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
            <case regex="true">
                <drop/>
            </case>
            <default>
                <call/>
                <respond/>
            </default>
        </switch>
    </sequence>
    <!-- You can add any flat sequences, endpoints, etc.. to this synapse.xml file if you do
    *not* want to keep the artifacts in several files -->
    <inboundEndpoint name="test" onError="fault" protocol="ws"
        sequence="dispatchSeq" suspend="false">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="inbound.ws.port">9091</parameter>
            <parameter name="ws.client.side.broadcast.level">0</parameter>
            <parameter name="ws.outflow.dispatch.sequence">outDispatchSeq</parameter>
            <parameter name="ws.outflow.dispatch.fault.sequence">fault</parameter>
        </parameters>
    </inboundEndpoint>
</definitions>
```

I was able to successfully test it with Nett client:

```
C:\work\servers\netty>java -Durl=ws://localhost:9091/websocket -DsubProtocol="synapse(contentType='application/xml')" -cp netty-example-4.1.4.Final.jar;lib/*;. io.netty.example.http.websocketx.client.WebSocketClient
WebSocket Client connected!
```

However if I try to test it from JavaScript code I am getting error like:

[image]

Do you know what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs because SockJS internally trying to load the URL using `XMLHttpRequest`, but Chrome does not allow accessing cross origin content unless the protocol is one of the aforementioned protocols (In this case it is `ws://)`. I have tried a similar scenario with Firefox and it works fine since it doesn't have this Chrome specific limitation.

In this scenario since WSO2 ESB exposes a WebSocket interface to invoke the HTTP Endpoint, you can use native HTML5 WebSocket implementation as follows.

```js
var url = 'ws://localhost:9091/websocket';
var ws = new WebSocket(url);

ws.onopen = function() {
  // todo
}

ws.onmessage = function(e) {
  // todo
}
```